# Conflicting dependencies error while trying to setup tensorflow

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, command-line-interface, tensorflow2.0

I'm following this guide https://youtu.be/rRwflsS67ow and right around 11:30 I get an error that I don't know how to solve (or if I should even solve it). This is it:

```
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.6/1.6 MB 816.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of sacrebleu to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting sacrebleu<=2.2.0
  Downloading sacrebleu-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 92.0/92.0 kB 174.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyparsing to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of object-detection to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install object-detection and object-detection==0.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tf-models-official 2.11.5 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.4 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.3 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.0 depends on opencv-python-headless==4.5.2.52
    object-detection 0.1 depends on sacrebleu<=2.2.0
    tf-models-official 2.10.1 depends on sacrebleu==2.2.0
    tf-models-official 2.10.0 depends on opencv-python-headless==4.5.2.52
    tf-models-official 2.9.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.9.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.9.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.8.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.5.1 depends on tensorflow-addons

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

What should I do now? I checked out the link that the ERROR message gave me but I don't really understand what's it talking about, so that's why I'm here. Also note: This my 1st time using anaconda, tensorflow and anything machine-learning related (I'm also not very familiar with the CLI, only on a basic level).

If you know how to fix this please do let me know.

EDIT: Yeah I have to fix it.

I tried to just move on but then when trying to test everything out with `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py` I get this error:

```
(tfa2) C:\Users\PATH-THING\TF 2nd attempt\models\research>python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PATH-THING\TF 2nd attempt\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    from absl.testing import parameterized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'
```

Comment: I recommend you try to put all useful info in the question, in order to raise the chances of finding someone willing to help. Personally, I will not watch the video to figure out what the context of the issue is.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815799/having-trouble-installing-tf-object-detection-with-pip